# How can I access files on a Seagate GoFlex Satellite wifi or Kingston Wi-Drive?

Tags: wi-fi, file-system

My final goal is to programmaticaly access files on a Wifi/USB storage device, like a Seagate GoFlex Satellite wifi or Kingston Wi-Drive (preferred because less expensive).

The storage devices are made to be connected to a PC by USB and also can be connected to Android (and iPhone) by wifi.

Once connected, it is possible to put files on the hard drive over wifi using a custom Android application provided by the manufacturer (like [Kingston Wi-drive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kingston.widrive) or [Seagate GoFlex Access™ app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.seagate.goflexhome&hl=fr))? How do they do this? Can I access on my filesystem with program like [Astro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) ?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking here. If you're looking for help with a programming solution, you'll want [so], not here. (Please read the [FAQ].) If I'm misunderstanding you, I think you're going to need to clarify your question.

Comment: not sure ... if you can access on that two device from astro or a file manager like this it means that you can access programmaticaly on that two device. If I put my question on stackoverflow, they will tell me that the question is android device oriented. So I'm not sure of  the correct web site

Comment: The fact that your question relates to Android doesn't make it off topic for Stack Overflow (nor does it make it *on* topic here). If you're trying to write a program to access the data then this is not the correct site. If you just want to access the data however possible (i.e. if "Use Astro" solves your problem) then this fits here.

Comment: well I don't know, my first need is use it with my application, but if someone has one of that device and he can access with an astro application, it should work

Comment: Well if you have two distinct questions then just ask *one* of them. "How do I access a wifi drive from Android?" seems perfectly acceptable here, and is an entirely different question than "How do I write an app to access a wireless drive?"

Comment: @P.Sohm I've edited your question to hopefully make it a bit clearer, as it wasn't easy to understand what you were trying to do. If I have got any of the details wrong, please feel free to correct them.

Comment: done. hope to be clear. feel free to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this review [Pocket-Lint: Kingston Wi-Drive review](http://www.pocket-lint.com/review/5724/kingston-technology-wi-drive-wi-fi-flash-storage-drive-review) :

> You are also able to access the files on the Wi-Drive on a PC or Mac
>   by visiting it's IP address in your web browser. This, again, allows
>   you to play any files that are supported in your web browser. MP3s,
>   for example, play fine, but you might struggle more with video files.
>
> You can also connect to the Kingston as a regular network drive. We
>   were able to view it as if it was any network attached storage device.
>   That means we could also copy files over wirelessly too.

This suggests that, the Kingston at least, supports something like [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (the Windows file-sharing protocol). Many Android apps let you connect to an SMB shared drive to copy files on or off, I use [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) to copy files from my Windows machines to my phone/tablet this way, and I'm pretty sure Astro supports it too.

To do this from your app, you just need to include SMB file access support in your Andoird app. How to do that is off-topic for this site, as that is a developer question.

Comment: well I know how to make a smb / cifs file access with jcifs. I already developed it. My need is only to know is how to access to that device and I think you gave me a good answer. thank you